# Where's the iPhone MIME type database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a program for the iPhone that is supposed to be doing intelligent things (picking out appropriate icons for file types) given a list of filenames.  I'm looking for the iPhone take on something like /etc/mime.types or something similar- an API call is what I'm assuming would be available for the phone.  Does this exist?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If it did, your app surely wouldn't have permissions to even read it directly.  What are you trying to do?

**EDIT**

This is a function I wrote a while ago.  I wrote it for the Mac, but it looks like the same functions exist on the iPhone.  Basically, you give it a filename, and it uses the path extension to return the file's MIME type:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
...
- (NSString*) fileMIMEType:(NSString*) file {
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (CFStringRef)[file pathExtension], NULL);
    CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass (UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    return [(NSString *)MIMEType autorelease];
}
```

Comment: `Does not work on iPhone` - my bad. You need to include the MobileCoreServices framework, and `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`

Comment: I'm having a problem with this code with a pdf file on one iPad device (iPad 1st gen / 5.1.1), but not another (iPad 3 / 5.1.1) or in Simulator (5.1). The pathExtension is pdf, and UTI comes back OK as com.adobe.pdf, but the MIMEType returns nil.

Is there anything that might cause this? Can a MIMEType registry get corrupted on a device?

Comment: @slf yes, that's fundamentally equivalent to what's in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The following function will return the mime-type for a given file extension in **Swift 2**

```
import MobileCoreServices

func mimeTypeFromFileExtension(fileExtension: String) -> String? {
    guard let uti: CFString = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension as NSString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let mimeType: CFString = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
        return nil
    }

    return mimeType as String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In obj-C, warning to memory leaks when using C.

```
- (NSString *)guessMIMETypeFromFileName: (NSString *)fileName {
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)[fileName pathExtension], NULL);
    CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    if (!MIMEType) {
        return @"application/octet-stream";
    }
    NSString *dest = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge NSString *)(MIMEType)];
    CFRelease(MIMEType);

    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the great and accepted answer to **Swift 5.3**, as an URL extension

```
extension URL {
    var mime: String {
        guard
            let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension as CFString, nil)
        else { return "" }
        let mime = uti.takeRetainedValue() as String
        uti.release()
        return mime
    }
}
```