# Document Type Description or 'Kind' Description

Tags: iphone, file

Given a file type (eg, DOC or PDF), how does one get a description similar to Finder's 'Kind'? For example, under Finder, DOC Kind is 'Word 97 Format (.doc)', and PDF Kind is 'Portable Document Format (PDF).

According to [About Document Interaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403), " iOS provides a systemwide registry of file type associations". But I don't believe I am pulling out the correct information (I'm not even really sure I'm using the aforementioned registry).

I'm using the code below, and it is returning 'com.microsoft.word.doc' for a DOC's kind. RTF is 'public.rtf', and PDF is 'com.adobe.pdf'. More bizarre is a link (webloc): 'dyn.age81s3pcrv10g'. None of the descriptions are user friendly.

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPathName];
if(url == nil)
  return [extension uppercaseString];    // i.e., PDF

UIDocumentInteractionController* doc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: url];     
if(doc == nil)
  return [extension uppercaseString];    // i.e., PDF

return doc.UTI;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code to get the description. For example, a PDF files retrieves 'Portable Document Format (PDF)'.

To use the code on the iPhone, add the MobileCoreServices framework and `#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`. Error checking and ASSERTs have been omitted for clarity.

```
NSString* extension = [filename pathExtension];
NSString* hint = @"public.data";

CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (CFStringRef)extension, (CFStringRef)hint);
[(NSString *)uti autorelease];

CFStringRef mime = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass (uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
[(NSString *)mime autorelease];

CFStringRef description = UTTypeCopyDescription(uti);
[(NSString*)description autorelease];

NSLog(@"%@: %@", filename, description);
```

==========================================

Stack Overflow:
[Where's the iPhone MIME type database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439020/wheres-the-iphone-mime-type-database)

Apple: [Adopting Uniform Type Identifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis.tasks/understand_utis_tasks.html)

Comment: Worth mentioning: `hint = @"public.data";` specifies that a file's UTI is desired. Folders also have UTI information (see Apple's Adopting Uniform Type Identifiers).