# How do I know the MIME type for image data in UIPasteboard?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage, uipasteboard

I want to import an image from `UIPasteboard`. The `dataForPasteboardType:` method gives me `NSData` of the image, but I have no idea whether that’s a GIF, PNG, JPEG or whatever. I can create an `UIImage` from the data without knowing the precise image type, but I’d like to have the MIME type for further processing. Is there a way to get it without analyzing the raw bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be helpful, is a method to get the MIME type from a file path:
[Determine MIME Type of NSData Loaded From a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996797/determine-mime-type-of-nsdata-loaded-from-a-file)