# How to attach files to UIActivityTypeMail?

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, fileshare

I like to share files (images, videos, pdf, plist, txt…) with UIActivityViewController, I am trying to share a NSData object, but it wont work. If I replace the NSData with UIImage it works.

Is it possible to add this to the UIActivityViewController: `[mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:[[self.filePath lastPathComponent] pathExtension]   fileName:[self.filePath lastPathComponent]];`

Comment: Why aren't you using correct mime types?

Comment: I found that online, is there a mime type for all files?

Comment: File types: http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: OK, so no no mime type for all file types. Anyway, can you help me to attach a any file to the email?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach raw data you should use an appropriate mime type, like

```
application/octet-stream
```

And preferably set an appropriate file name and extension (like .bin    )

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996797/determine-mime-type-of-nsdata-loaded-from-a-file) to determine the mime type for files.

Comment: I dont want to attach .bin files, I want to be able to attach all files.

Comment: See the edit, try to determine the correct mime type for the files.

Comment: OK, I'll look into it later. But do you know how to add any file as NSData to the email in UIActivityViewController?

Comment: You need to look at `UIActivityItemProvider` and how it works with the controller.