# Determine MIME type from NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mime-types, nsdata

How would you determine the mime type for an NSData object? I plan to have the user to upload a video/picture from their iPhone and have that file be wrapped in a NSData class.

I was wondering if I can tell the mime type from the NSData. There are only a few answers to this question and the most recent one is from 2010 (4 years ago!). Thanks!

```
NSData *data; // can be an image or video
NSString *mimeType = [data getMimetype]; // how would I implement getMimeType
```

Comment: You could have another field that declares the MIME type and send that along as well.

Comment: There is no (accurate) way to determine the MIME type of data from the data itself.  At best you can make an educated guess.

Comment: Should you wish to add extra MIME types, you can find their hex values here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 54):

Based on [ml's answer from a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5042365/2042510), I've added the mime types determination for NSData:

ObjC:

```
+ (NSString *)mimeTypeForData:(NSData *)data {
    uint8_t c;
    [data getBytes:&c length:1];

    switch (c) {
        case 0xFF:
            return @"image/jpeg";
            break;
        case 0x89:
            return @"image/png";
            break;
        case 0x47:
            return @"image/gif";
            break;
        case 0x49:
        case 0x4D:
            return @"image/tiff";
            break;
        case 0x25:
            return @"application/pdf";
            break;
        case 0xD0:
            return @"application/vnd";
            break;
        case 0x46:
            return @"text/plain";
            break;
        default:
            return @"application/octet-stream";
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Swift:

```
static func mimeType(for data: Data) -> String {

    var b: UInt8 = 0
    data.copyBytes(to: &b, count: 1)

    switch b {
    case 0xFF:
        return "image/jpeg"
    case 0x89:
        return "image/png"
    case 0x47:
        return "image/gif"
    case 0x4D, 0x49:
        return "image/tiff"
    case 0x25:
        return "application/pdf"
    case 0xD0:
        return "application/vnd"
    case 0x46:
        return "text/plain"
    default:
        return "application/octet-stream"
    }
}
```

This handle main file types only, but you can complete it to fit your needs: all the files signature are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), just use the same pattern as I did.

PS: all the corresponding mime types are available [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Comment: Hey @blee908, this could be a valid answer, what do you think? :)

Comment: How can we detect Audio files ?

Comment: @Ankush check the list of signatures as mentioned above https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: then find the audio file types you want to detect and a case for each file type.    Example: according to the array of files signature, WMA first byte is 0x30    so add case 0x30: return @"audio/x-ms-wma"; break;

Comment: This can return a lot of false positives.

Comment: @maddy thank you for letting us know, but it doesn't really help to understand why or how to fix the false positive cases...

Comment: @Tib How can we add support for docx file?

Comment: @JigarTarsariya As I mentioned in my original answer, please have a look at the mime types list available here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures. Docx is mentioned.

Comment: @Tib for .doc extension files I am getting application/vnd rather that application/wsword..I am not sure why is that

Comment: what about doc ? docx ?

Answer (score 38):

❤️ Swift

```swift
extension Data {
    private static let mimeTypeSignatures: [UInt8 : String] = [
        0xFF : "image/jpeg",
        0x89 : "image/png",
        0x47 : "image/gif",
        0x49 : "image/tiff",
        0x4D : "image/tiff",
        0x25 : "application/pdf",
        0xD0 : "application/vnd",
        0x46 : "text/plain",
        ]

    var mimeType: String {
        var c: UInt8 = 0
        copyBytes(to: &c, count: 1)
        return Data.mimeTypeSignatures[c] ?? "application/octet-stream"
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: can we set type for doc or ppt file ?

Comment: This can return a lot of false positives.

Comment: what about doc? or docx ???

Answer (score 4):

Since you say that you're *uploading* this data, you should already know the MIME type. You created the data object, you know where the data came from, and there are a limited number of MIME types. So use whichever one applies to your data. For an image it's probably `image/jpeg` or `image/png`. For videos there are a bunch of `video/` types. You can find a long list of MIME type strings on your Mac in `/etc/apache2/mime.types`. You'll want one or more of those depending on what kind of video you have.

Determining the MIME type is a sticky problem; an `NSData` can encode any kind of binary data. The only way to determine what was encoded is to examine the bytes. That in turn means having some understanding of what byte streams exist in different file types. It should be possible to use a lookup dictionary in many (but not all) cases, and there might be an open source implementation somewhere for common file types. To get an idea of what's involved, try `man file` on your Mac and look in `/usr/share/file/magic/` to see how various file types are identified (the `file` command doesn't produce MIME types but it does analyze file contents to try and identify file types, so it's the same principle).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Well, the backstory is a bit more complicated.  I'm writing an API call and I don't know what the user is passing in. All I know is that its an NSData class and it can be a image or video. And I need the MIME type too properly upload the file via AFNetworking.

Comment: Does your server need to know the exact MIME type? You can always fall back on `application/octet-stream` to indicate "some kind of binary data". If you need something more specific, the best way might be to load it into an `AVFoundation` class (maybe `AVAsset`) and then look at the metadata to choose a MIME type.

Comment: Very close. It turns out that "application/octet-stream" seems to work (i tested png and jpeg, but entered in the same MIME type), but AFNetworking needs to know the file extension, so you need to pass in an NSString *filename with "mypic.jpeg" or "mypic.png" not "mypic"

Comment: OK, well, I don't use AFNetworking, so I don't know about that. It's open source though, so changing it is always an option.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `NSData` is a just a data object that wraps a byte array:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

...so one way I can think of if you wanted to discover its MIME type is to inspect the bytes themselves and then surmise the type from there. There's an example of that in here: [Finding image type from NSData or UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147311/finding-image-type-from-nsdata-or-uiimage)

I also found this: [Determine MIME Type of NSData Loaded From a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996797/determine-mime-type-of-nsdata-loaded-from-a-file); which refers to some internal database (I guess) that can be used for a MIME type look-up.

But like Tom Harrington says in his answer, it could get tricky depending on what you're dealing with.

**Edit...**

Of course, that second solution relies on the file extension, which you obviously don't have, but I'm sure you noticed that already.