# Can I verify Data if image using foundation framework only

Tags: swift, vapor

Is it possible, using swift, to verify `data: Data` is image using `Foundation.framework` only?

Nothing else from macOS or iOS is available as this is for Server side project only (Vapor)

Comment: I am a little confused. You want to see if data is an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you have is the byte array, this might help: [Determine MIME type from NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789770/determine-mime-type-from-nsdata).

If you're uploading through multipart, you should have access to the filename (and possibly other data) that you could use to detect whether it's an image. Although this could be spoofed.

Client side validation might also be useful here.