# Get Mime Type from NSURL

Tags: ios, alamofire, nsurl

I'm developping an app using a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to choose file to send to a server.

I have to retrieve the `Mime Type` of this file in order to correctly send this file with `Amalofire` :

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, url, headers: headers, multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    if let url = attachment as? NSURL, let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: data, name :"File\(i)",  fileName: "file\(i).\(url.pathExtension)", mimeType: "???")
    }
}
```

Is there any method able to get the mime type from extension or NSURL ?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789770/determine-mime-type-from-nsdata - might help

Comment: Doesn't handle all file types...

Comment: yes - you'll need to add the rest, you have the info in the best answer, if you don't find anything already coded you'll need to do it yourself. It shouldn't be very challenging just time consuming

Answer (score 2):

I've found that and works well :

```
internal let DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE = "application/octet-stream"

internal let mimeTypes = [
"html": "text/html",
"htm": "text/html",
"shtml": "text/html",
"css": "text/css",
"xml": "text/xml",
"gif": "image/gif",
"jpeg": "image/jpeg",
"jpg": "image/jpeg",
"js": "application/javascript",
"atom": "application/atom+xml",
"rss": "application/rss+xml",
"mml": "text/mathml",
"txt": "text/plain",
"jad": "text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor",
"wml": "text/vnd.wap.wml",
"htc": "text/x-component",
"png": "image/png",
"tif": "image/tiff",
"tiff": "image/tiff",
"wbmp": "image/vnd.wap.wbmp",
"ico": "image/x-icon",
"jng": "image/x-jng",
"bmp": "image/x-ms-bmp",
"svg": "image/svg+xml",
"svgz": "image/svg+xml",
"webp": "image/webp",
"woff": "application/font-woff",
"jar": "application/java-archive",
"war": "application/java-archive",
"ear": "application/java-archive",
"json": "application/json",
"hqx": "application/mac-binhex40",
"doc": "application/msword",
"pdf": "application/pdf",
"ps": "application/postscript",
"eps": "application/postscript",
"ai": "application/postscript",
"rtf": "application/rtf",
"m3u8": "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl",
"xls": "application/vnd.ms-excel",
"eot": "application/vnd.ms-fontobject",
"ppt": "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
"wmlc": "application/vnd.wap.wmlc",
"kml": "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml",
"kmz": "application/vnd.google-earth.kmz",
"7z": "application/x-7z-compressed",
"cco": "application/x-cocoa",
"jardiff": "application/x-java-archive-diff",
"jnlp": "application/x-java-jnlp-file",
"run": "application/x-makeself",
"pl": "application/x-perl",
"pm": "application/x-perl",
"prc": "application/x-pilot",
"pdb": "application/x-pilot",
"rar": "application/x-rar-compressed",
"rpm": "application/x-redhat-package-manager",
"sea": "application/x-sea",
"swf": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
"sit": "application/x-stuffit",
"tcl": "application/x-tcl",
"tk": "application/x-tcl",
"der": "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
"pem": "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
"crt": "application/x-x509-ca-cert",
"xpi": "application/x-xpinstall",
"xhtml": "application/xhtml+xml",
"xspf": "application/xspf+xml",
"zip": "application/zip",
"bin": "application/octet-stream",
"exe": "application/octet-stream",
"dll": "application/octet-stream",
"deb": "application/octet-stream",
"dmg": "application/octet-stream",
"iso": "application/octet-stream",
"img": "application/octet-stream",
"msi": "application/octet-stream",
"msp": "application/octet-stream",
"msm": "application/octet-stream",
"docx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
"xlsx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
"pptx": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
"mid": "audio/midi",
"midi": "audio/midi",
"kar": "audio/midi",
"mp3": "audio/mpeg",
"ogg": "audio/ogg",
"m4a": "audio/x-m4a",
"ra": "audio/x-realaudio",
"3gpp": "video/3gpp",
"3gp": "video/3gpp",
"ts": "video/mp2t",
"mp4": "video/mp4",
"mpeg": "video/mpeg",
"mpg": "video/mpeg",
"mov": "video/quicktime",
"webm": "video/webm",
"flv": "video/x-flv",
"m4v": "video/x-m4v",
"mng": "video/x-mng",
"asx": "video/x-ms-asf",
"asf": "video/x-ms-asf",
"wmv": "video/x-ms-wmv",
"avi": "video/x-msvideo"
]

internal func MimeType(ext: String?) -> String {
if ext != nil && mimeTypes.contains({ $0.0 == ext!.lowercaseString }) {
        return mimeTypes[ext!.lowercaseString]!
    }
    return DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE
}

extension NSURL {
    public func mimeType() -> String {
        return MimeType(self.pathExtension)
    }
}


extension NSString {
    public func mimeType() -> String {
        return MimeType(self.pathExtension)
    }
}

extension String {
    public func mimeType() -> String {
        return (self as NSString).mimeType()
    }
}
```

From [here](https://gist.github.com/ngs/918b07f448977789cf69)

Answer (score 2):

This Gist worked for me: https://gist.github.com/Krivoblotsky/4d5e7c94cd4171b431d0 Here is my adoption:

```
+ (NSString *)urlToMIME:(NSURL *)url {
    CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[url pathExtension];
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);
    CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)MIMEType;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this extension:

```
import Foundation
import MobileCoreServices

extension URL {
    func mimeType() -> String {
        let pathExtension = self.pathExtension
        if let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension as NSString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() {
            if let mimetype = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue() {
                return mimetype as String
            }
        }
        return "application/octet-stream"
    }
    var containsImage: Bool {
        let mimeType = self.mimeType()
        guard let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
            return false
        }
        return UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeImage)
    }
    var containsAudio: Bool {
        let mimeType = self.mimeType()
        guard let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
            return false
        }
        return UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeAudio)
    }
    var containsVideo: Bool {
        let mimeType = self.mimeType()
        guard  let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
            return false
        }
        return UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeMovie)
    }

}
```