# How does one differentiate between Data types in a Swift URLSession completion handler?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsurlsession, urlsession

```
    _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask( with: request ) {
        data, response, error in
        // ...
    }
```

Assuming this code produces a successful load, `data` could be some JSON, or an image, or something else. What is [a way / the best way] to differentiate between different data types on response?

Or, perhaps, is it best to have multiples outlets for `URLSession` in one's app that each handle a different `Data` type?

Thank you for reading.

---

This question is not a duplicate of [Determine MIME type from NSData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789770/determine-mime-type-from-nsdata) because in order to discover that post, the searcher would be required to: 1. know what a MIME type is; and 2. know what they are for, and therefore use the keyword "MIME" in their search. Although the question posed by this post *is* answered by the "Determine MIME..." post, its relevance is in providing a searching bridge for people to whom the use of  MIME types isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: A proper implemented server should return the data type as well. Inspect the HTTP header field `Content-Type` which should contain the MIME type of the response.

Comment: Thanks @clemens. What is the "server" is just an image on a http url? And what is the server is someone else's server that I can't access that hasn't been properly implemented, how do I get the MIME type then?

Comment: You should check the responses with `curl`. With the option `-v` you can see all HTTP headers.

Comment: thanks again @clemens. and thank you to whoever upvoted the downvote this question at first received

Comment: Question for @dávid-pásztor: if you didn't know about the importance of MIME types in answering this question, how would you be able to search to find the post entitled "Determine MIME type from NSData?" on the site? This is the question that, for me, shows that my question is *not* a duplicate of "Determine MIME type from NSData?"

Comment: the above comment also applies to @rmaddy

Comment: and to @clemens

Comment: To assume that people have heard of MIME types and/or know what they are for breaks the principle of inclusivity. And it's 2018 everyone, inclusivity should come as standard.

Comment: ok @haroldo-gondim, sure, let's just let people who don't know that NS/Data objects contain useful MIME type information flounder in the darkness. I'm sure that's better