# get charset and mimetype in objective c

Tags: macos, file, character-encoding, mime-types, nstask

In mac OS X I can get charset and mimetype of file with this command

```
file -I /Users/bbb/Desktop/ba.py
```

And this command return this result

```
text/x-java; charset=us-ascii
```

Now I want get this mime type and charset in objective c **without** using **NSTask** or **System()** .

How I can get this info?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I used this link  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996797/determine-mime-type-of-nsdata-loaded-from-a-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363813/how-can-you-read-a-files-mime-type-in-objective-c but they did not correct respond base on file command and not return charset