# MFMailComposeViewController configure mimetype for attachment

Tags: iphone, sendmail

I need some help.
I am trying to attach files to mail using,
[mail addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:fileName];
but the problem is that if i need to send a .jpeg image i need to repeat code just for setting mime type to "mimeType:@"image/jpeg".
My question is that is there any general mimeType that can attach any kind of file irrespective of .doc,.ppt,.pdf or an audio or video file.
is there any general mimeType: for an kind of attachment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for mime type better search on google

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439038/246119)):

```
NSString* fileMIMEType(NSString * file) {
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (CFStringRef)[file pathExtension], NULL);
    CFStringRef MIMEType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass (UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    return [(NSString *)MIMEType autorelease];
}
```

You need to include the MobileCoreServices framework, and add:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

---

Another possible solution is an open source project [MagicKit](https://github.com/aidansteele/MagicKit).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use @"application/octet-stream", which means something like “Binary data file”

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL * fileURL1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoStr];
NSData *videofile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL1];
[picker addAttachmentData:videofile mimeType:@"video/quicktime" fileName:@"Video.mov"];
```

It will work fine for attaching video file in `mfmai`