# Classification of MIME Type for Mail sending?

Tags: iphone

I am confuse when m sending .mp3,.pdf,.mpeg or .exe file in MFMailComposeViewController because i have not idea about its MIME type. Can anybody tell the what are the MIME type for Iphone in Detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this question's answer.

[How can you read a files MIME-type in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363813/how-can-you-read-a-files-mime-type-in-objective-c)

Edit:
This link lists the MIME types:
http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Comment: i need classification like .jpg does exist in Image.What's the mime type for pdf and any other extentions...

Comment: for jpg it will be image/jpeg check the link for pdf etc.

Comment: that what i wana know.That where can i get any document which can show me the classification?

Comment: check this link I also edited it in my answer http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp  for pdf its application/pdf

Comment: it means MIME will remain same for Iphone ok thanx man. thanx a lot