# Get a file type from the contents and NOT from extension

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you read a files MIME-type in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363813/how-can-you-read-a-files-mime-type-in-objective-c)

In Cocoa, I am trying to get file type, I.E. JPG, JPEG, or PNG, using

```
LSCopyKindStringForURL((CFURLRef)URL, (CFStringRef *)&kind);
```

This helps only when the file extension is valid. However, if I rename a PNG file extension to JPEG, it returns JPEG, because LSCopyKindStringForURL returns file type from extension.

Is there any other method that will return me the exact type from the underlying contents of the file?

Answer (score 1):

There is [MagicKit.framework](http://github.com/aidansteele/MagicKit/tree/), which is a wrapper around `libmagic`. (This is what the `file` command uses). In my tests, its determining of UTIs could maybe use a bit of work, but it's probably a good start.

The majority of Launch Services APIs and the like don't look internally at the file's data, AFAIK. That said, the frameworks that would actually deal with such data (in this case of image data, ImageIO.framework, NSImage, etc.), can usually cope with such discrepancies. (For example, change a PNG file extension to .gif, and Preview.app will still gladly open it.)

Comment: I found the solution. You need to get metadata of the file using Core Graphics framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL( (CFURLRef) URL, NULL);
NSDictionary* metadata = (NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source,0,NULL);
```

Comment: Don't forget to release these objects.