# UIWebView on iOS 10 beta: not loading any svg images

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

We are developing a cordova ios application and we recently installed xcode 8-beta to see how our app would run under ios 10.
So far we've noticed only one issue: svg images are not loading. These images are set as background using css for various elements, and they all work fine under 9.3.2 and below.

Comment: Same issue here... In-line Base 64 encoded svg images seem to be working fine. I noticed that the svg images load fine on the simulator, but fail to load on a physical iPhone running iOS 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your cordova app uses a plugin that implements [`URLProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlprotocol), such as the [phonegap contentsync plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync), you could be seeing a bug with the SVG's response header's MIME Type.

Prior to iOS 10, the MIME Type was being set automatically, possibly as a feature of the API (yet to confirm), but that no longer seems to be the case. You can work around the problem by explicitly setting the MIME Type (`Content-Type`) of the response during [`[URLProtocol startloading]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlprotocol/1408989-startloading?language=objc#discussion):

(Adapted from [phonegap contentsync](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync/blob/0bd6dbe03d7ad2bfec5847590ed381d3e4e374b3/src/ios/ContentSync.m) and this [MIME Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363813/how-can-you-read-a-files-mime-type-in-objective-c/21858677#21858677))

```
- (void)startLoading {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.request.URL.path];

    NSString *fileExtension = self.request.URL.pathExtension;
    NSString *UTI = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)fileExtension, NULL);
    NSString *contentType = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);

    // add the MIME Type to the existing header.
    NSMutableDictionary *headers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.request.allHTTPHeaderFields];
    headers[@"Content-Type"] = contentType;

    // create a response using the request and our new HEADERs
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:self.request.URL
                                                              statusCode:200
                                                             HTTPVersion:@"1.1"
                                                            headerFields:headers];

    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:response
          cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly];
    [self.client URLProtocol:self didLoadData:data];
    [self.client URLProtocolDidFinishLoading:self];
}
```

Comment: FYI, this fix was recently [merged](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync/commit/efaf50a86e51168f7114a782910d40bf939fe89b) into phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

In case this help anyone else not looking to modify the URLProtocol code, I just replaced my `img` tags with `object` tags:

`<img src="img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" width="280" class="logo">`

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/logo.svg" width="280" class="logo">Logo</object>`

I understand this might not work for every case but it did the trick for me.