# How to get MIMETYPE of local file?

Tags: ios

I download some files, such as word, ppt, excel. But i don't know their MIMETYPE and suffix. Is there some way can get MIMETYPE of these file?

Comment: Have you try any code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363813/how-can-you-read-a-files-mime-type-in-objective-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you read a files MIME-type in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363813/how-can-you-read-a-files-mime-type-in-objective-c)

Comment: But I don't know their suffix,these way can't work.

Comment: Content-Type is zip，but they are Microsoft Office File.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the suffix, you're forced to look at the file contents. Typically this starts with looking for [magic bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), the first few bytes of the file. You can often qualify the type of file on that basis (though you obviously can't be sure unless you validate the whole file).

For modern Office documents, they should conform to [OOXML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats) and the first two bytes should be 0x50 0x4b (i.e. "PK") the indicator of a zip file.

You can then uncompress it (e.g. with [ZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive)).

You can then either parse the docProps/app.xml or see [Office Open XML](http://officeopenxml.com/index.php) site with links at the top of the page for how to parse word processing, excel, and presentations, respectively.